# How to Devise Combinatorial Arguments for Proving Identities

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

What are some strategies or tips for contriving/devising combinatorial arguments?

[Combinatorial proof for $\binom{n}{a}\binom{a}{k}\binom{n-a}{b-k} = \binom{n}{b}\binom{b}{k}\binom{n-b}{a-k}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69315/combinatorial-proof-for-binomna-binomak-binomn-ab-k-binomnb)

I might divine that $\{a\}, \{b\} \subseteq \{n\}$, but how and why would you [realise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69334/53259)  :

LHS = # of ways to pick either team $\times $ # of ways to pick all leaders for both teams
RHS =  $\times $ # of ways to pick all leaders for both teams $\times $ # of ways to pick either team

> [Help with combinatorial proof of binomial identity: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2{n\choose k}^2 = n^2{2n-2\choose n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/help-with-combinatorial-proof-of-binomial-identity-sum-limits-k-1nk2n-ch).   ([Similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469559/proving-sum-k-0nkn-choose-k2-n2n-1-choose-n-1/469608#469608))

RHS: The $2n - 2$ suggest that out of the $2n$ things, the $2$ subtracted may be special roles. Then?

LHS: How would $k^2\binom{n}{k}^2$ divulge: For each of the $1 \le k \le n$ women,
$LHS =$ the # of ways to select women $ \times $ the # of ways to select the female cocaptain
$ \times $ the # of ways to select the male cocaptain $ \times $  the # of ways to select the male players?

> P18, Ex 1.12(c), *A 1st Course in Pr*, Ross: $\sum_{k=0}^n {k^3 {n \choose k}} = n^2(2n + 3)2^{n - 3}$

The RHS has no binomial coefficients, so how would you divine/previse to consider all 5 cases of: the total # of ways of forming a committee of $n$ people with a chair, secretary:

$1.$ Chair = Secretary = Treasurer.
$2.$ Chair = Secretary, $\qquad 3.$ Secretary = Treasurer, $\qquad 4.$ Chair = Treasurer.
$5.$ Chair $\neq$ Secretary $\neq$ Treasurer.

With alternating signs, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503694/combinatorial-interpretation-of-an-alternating-binomial-sum/513100#513100) requiring a wily change of variable is still more intricate.